# How to remove "type" keyword in TypeScript auto-imports?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

Since a few days ago, when I auto-import something in VSCode in an Angular project, the import looks like this :

```js
import type { JobPostingSurvey } from '@gri/interfaces';
```

Is it possible to remove the `type` keyword and go back to previous TypeScript imports?

```js
import { JobPostingSurvey } from '@gri/interfaces';
```

This kind of unsuspected change really doesn't fit in an enterprise setting :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior only exists in the TypeScript 3.8-beta and will likely be removed before the final 3.8 release. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36038) for a discussion of the problem and proposed changes